# Translate a German paper by Hilbert

Tags: legendre-polynomials, translation-request, mathematical-german

Please translate Hilbert's paper [Ein Beitrag zur Theorie des Legendre'schen Polynoms](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yVJ91qLq9yamRWMVphQWxhZm8/edit?usp=sharing). I cannot find an existing translation for it. Thanks:)

Comment: That's the kind of task you should be prepared to pay for, or to spend more time researching for a translation, not the kind of task to request of MSE volunteers! (Yes, *everyone* here volunteers their help!)

Comment: @amWhy It's five light pages. There's no harm in throwing out a request.

Comment: It's only 5 pages, and not a huge amount of text. If it was 10+ and dense, yeah, it's a little much. But this amounts to only 1.5 ish pages of translatable material.

Comment: Go for it, then, @Arkamis!  It's all yours!

Comment: @amWhy If it were in a language I had proficiency in, I would.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick I think you would be mercilessly criticized if it isn't 100% perfect if you're attempting to archive it in the annals of mathematics. I suspect a 5-page paper that, at a glance, appears to be relatively minor, on an internet site, will not face a firing squad if you provide a hackish attempt.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick Unfortunately I cannot figure out the ideas there by merely looking at the formulas.

Comment: @amWhy "Go for it, then!" Don't be so ridiculous. What's your argument, here, that because one person doesn't have the time or inclination to fulfill a request, therefore that request is too demanding and shouldn't even be posted?

Comment: @JackM If you'll notice, I did not vote to close. Nor did I say the OP was prohibited from posting his/her request. I was "put-off" by the imperative-istic title; the OP seems not to have realized that his/her request is significant, and it would have helped for him/her to acknowledge that, and add just wee-bit of context, perhaps. (How would getting a translation help him/her?, e.g.) I for one, sympathize *very* easily with the OP's on this site (if you haven't noticed), particularly when a request is written as a request, with a bit of motivation added.

Comment: @amWhy Fair enough. I assumed from your first comment that you were opposed to the question.

Comment: Note: This took about 3 hours.

Comment: I agree with @amWhy. The OP is rude, to say the least.

Comment: I wanted to try out how hard it actually is. It turns out that the typesetting of the formulas takes most time (and I am not slow at this) - which could be provided by the person who needs a translation. The text translation could be put on several shoulders plus some final edit passes on the whole. Modern papers would pose copyright problems. So it is possible to do this here, but it would need a bit more software support, if this would be a regular task.

Comment: I feel sorry to see that some people have criticized me as "rude", maybe I should have written the question more politely. And I must say sorry to @mvw, I should have typed in the formulas myself. But I'm really confused why my question is "off-topic"? Isn't there a tag called "translation request"? Also, I want to know where I can seek help for translations if it's not suitable in MSE.(except Google, its translations are too terrible)

Comment: A nice colaborative translation site should be possible with the current web technology. If there is no good offer, let us try to create one.

Comment: @the_fox: What do you mean when you say "The OP is rude, to say the least."

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying. What is there to explain?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**[Acta mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Mathematica) 18, printed April 3rd, [1894](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1894)**

A CONTRIBUTION TO THE THEORY OF THE LEGENDRE POLYNOMIAL

BY

[DAVID HILBERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_hilbert)

[Königsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nigsberg), Prussia

This communication at hand is about the question of the smallest value different from $0$ which the integral

$$
I = \int\limits_\alpha^\beta \left[ f(x) \right]^2 \, dx \quad (\beta \gt \alpha)
$$

is able to attain, if one chooses for $f(x)$ a polynomial (lit.: "whole rational function") of degree $n - 1$ with integer coefficients and if one understands $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as given constants.

If one sets

$$
f(x) = a_1 x^{n - 1} + a_2 x^{n - 2} + \cdots + a_n
$$

the integral turns into a positive quadratic form of the $n$ variables $a_1$, $a_2, \ldots, a_n$:

$$
I = \sum^{i,k} \alpha_{ik} a_i a_k, \quad (i, k = 1, 2, \ldots, n)
$$

whose coefficients are given by the formula

$$
\alpha_{ik} = 
\int\limits_\alpha^\beta x^{2n-i-k} dx =
\frac{\beta^{2n-i-k+1}-\alpha^{2n-i-k+1}}{2n-i-k+1} 
$$

To get an upper bound for the minimum of this quadratic form $I$ it is needed to calculate its [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)

$$
D_{\alpha \beta} =
\left|
\begin{matrix} 
\alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & \cdots & \alpha_{1n} \\
\alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} & \cdots & \alpha_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\alpha_{n1} & \alpha_{n2} & \cdots & \alpha_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right| .
$$

*(end of page 1)*

If we replace in this determinant each element by its integral expression and thereby use for all elements of the first horizontal row the integration variable $x = x_1$, for all elements of the $2^{\tiny\mbox{nd}}, \ldots, n^{\tiny\mbox{th}}$ horizontal row regarding the integration variables $x = x_2, \ldots, x_n$, the discriminant of the quadratic form $I$ is represented as $n$-fold integral of the following form:

$$
D_{\alpha \beta} = 
\int\limits_\alpha^\beta \ldots \int\limits_\alpha^\beta
x_1^{n-1} x_2^{n-2} \ldots x_n^0
\prod^{i,k}(x_i - x_k) dx_1 \ldots dx_n .
$$

The interchange of the $n$ integration variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and
the addition of the resulting equations gives

$$
D_{\alpha \beta} = 
\frac{1}{\left|\underline{n}\right.}
\int\limits_\alpha^\beta
\ldots
\int\limits_\alpha^\beta
\prod^{i,k} (x_i - x_k)^2 dx_1 \ldots dx_n
$$

and if we -- using

$$
x_i = \frac{1}{2}(\beta - \alpha) y_i + \frac{1}{2}(\beta + \alpha)
$$

introduce the new integration variables $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, 
we obtain the formula

$$
D_{\alpha \beta} =
\left(
\frac{\beta - \alpha}{2}
\right)^{n^2} D, 
$$

where for abbreviation $D = D_{-1, +1}$ has been set.

For example it follows for $\alpha = 0$, $\beta = 1$

$$
D = 2^n
\left|
\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \cdots \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \cdots \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}
\right|
= 2^{n^2}
\left|
\begin{matrix} 
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & 
\cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} &
\cdots & \frac{1}{n + 1} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & 
\cdots & \frac{1}{n + 2} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} & \frac{1}{n+3} &
\cdots & \frac{1}{2n - 1} 
\end{matrix}
\right| .
$$

*(end of page 2)*

To calculate $D$ we develop the polynomial (lit.: "whole rational function") $f(x)$ into a progressing series of Legendre polynomials $X_m$.
Because of

$$
x^m = c_m X_m + c_m' X_{m-1} + \cdots + c_m^{(m)} X_0,
$$

where

$$
c_m = \frac{\left| \underline{m} \right.}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2m-1)},
$$

we get

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &=
a_1 (c_{n-1} X_{n-1} + c_{n-1}' X_{n-2} + \cdots) +
a_2 (c_{n-2} X_{n-2} + c_{n-2}' X_{n-3} + \cdots) + \cdots \\
&= c_{n-1} a_1 X_{n-1} +
(c_{n-1}' a_1 + c_{n-2} a_2) X_{n-2} +
(c_{n-1}'' a_1 + c_{n-2}' a_2 + c_{n-3} a_3 X_{n-3}) + \cdots
\end{align}
$$

and with the help of the formulas

$$
\int\limits_{-1}^{+1} X_m^2 dx = \frac{2}{2m+1}, \quad
\int\limits_{-1}^{+1} X_m X_k dx = 0 \quad
(m \ne k)
$$

it therefore follows

$$
\left[ I \right]_{\alpha = -1 \atop \beta = +1} =
\int\limits_{-1}^{+1} f^2(x) \, dx =
\frac{2}{2n-1} b_1^2 +
\frac{2}{2n-3} b_2^2 +
\frac{2}{2n-5} b_3^2 + \cdots ,
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
b_1 &= c_{n-1} a_1, \\
b_2 &= c_{n-1}' a_1 + c_{n-2} a_2, \\
b_3 &= c_{n-1}'' a_1 + c_{n-2}' a_2 + c_{n-3} a_3, \\
. \,\,\, & . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . 
\,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, . \,\,\, .
\end{align}
$$

has been set. Because of this representation as sum of squares of linear forms one wins for the disciminant $D$ the value

$$
\begin{align}
D &=
\frac{2^n}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \ldots (2n-1)}
(c_0 c_1 \cdots c_{n-1})^2 \\
&= 2^{n^2} 
\frac{\left\{
1^{n-1} 2^{n-2} \ldots (n-2)^2 (n-1)^1 
\right\}^4}{1^{2n-1} 2^{2n-2} \ldots (2n-2)^2 (2n-1)^1}
\end{align}
$$

and herein is the right side exactly identical with
$\frac{2^{n^2}}{\Delta}$ where $\Delta$ means that value, which I, in my treatise "About the Discriminant of the in the Finite terminating Hypergeometric Series" ("Über die Discriminante der im Endlichen abbrechenden hypergeometrischen Reihe") [1],

[1] [Crelle's Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crelle%27s_Journal), Vol. 103, p. 342.

*(end of page 3)*

got for the discriminant of a $n$-th degree Legendre polynomial under a  certain linear transformation. 
Under consideration of the formula for $D$ stated above, from this follows the result

> *The discriminant of the quadratic form $\int\limits_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx$ has the value 
>   $$
> \left|
> \begin{matrix} 
> 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & 
> \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
> \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} &
> \cdots & \frac{1}{n + 1} \\ 
> \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & 
> \cdots & \frac{1}{n + 2} \\ 
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} & \frac{1}{n+3} &
> \cdots & \frac{1}{2n - 1} 
> \end{matrix}
> \right| 
> =
> \frac{\left\{
> 1^{n-1} 2^{n-2} \ldots (n-2)^2 (n-1)^1 
> \right\}^4}{1^{2n-1} 2^{2n-2} \ldots (2n-2)^2 (2n-1)^1}
> $$
>   and is equal to the reciprocal value of the disciminant of 
>   the $n^{\tiny\mbox{th}}$ degree equation
>   $$
> \xi^n + 
> \binom{n}{1}^2 \xi^{n-1} +
> \binom{n}{2}^2 \xi^{n-2} + \ldots + 1 = 0, 
> $$
>   whose left side, by a linear transformation of the variable $\xi$, can be turned into the Legendre polynomial $X_n$.*

We now return to the original posed question.
Application of the Stirling forumla, if $N$ is a positive number,
delivers the equation

$$
N l 1 + (N-1) l 2 + \ldots + 
2 l (N-1) + 1 l N =
\frac{1}{2}N^2 l N - \frac{3}{4} N^2 (1 + \varepsilon_N),
$$

where $\varepsilon_N$ means a with growing $N$ vanishing number.
With the help of this formula one easily finds

$$
l D = (1 + \varepsilon_n') l (2^{-n^2}),
$$

*(end of page 4)*

where $\varepsilon_n'$ vanishes with growing $n$, i.e.

$$
D = \eta_n 2^{-n^2}
$$

and further

$$
D_{\alpha \beta} = 
\eta_n \left(
\frac{\beta - \alpha}{4}
\right)^{n^2},
$$

where $\eta_n$ approaches the unit with growing $n$.

Now it is, according to a theorem by [H. Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Minkowski) [2], always possible,
for a definite quadratic form, to choose the $n$ variables such that
the value of the quadratic form turns out less than the $n$-fold
of the $n^{\tiny \mbox{th}}$ root of its discriminant.
If therefore the positive difference $\beta - \alpha$ is assumed
less than $4$, it follows that it is always possible
to determine a polynomial (lit.: "whole rational function")
$f(x)$ with integer coefficients for which the value of
the integral $I = \int\limits_\alpha^\beta f^2(x)\,dx$ turns
out smaller than 
$n \eta_n' \left( \frac{|\beta - \alpha|}{4} \right)^n$.
But because $\eta_n'=\sqrt[n]{\eta_n}$ approaches the unit too
with growing $n$, we get the result

> *The integral $\int\limits_\alpha^\beta f^2(x) \, dx$ can
>   attain an arbitrary small positive value, if one chooses
>   the polynomial (lit.: "whole integer function") $f(x)$
>   properly, under the condition that the interval of
>   integration $\alpha$ to $\beta$ is smaller than $4$.*

Königsberg in Prussia, March 13th, 1893.

[2] Crelle's Journal, Vol. 107, p. 291.

*(end of page 5)*

*(Special thanks to Donald E. Knuth and the MathJax team)*

Comment: A downvote for a work in progress? Come the heck on, people.

Comment: Looks good so far, except that the word-for-word translation "whole rational function" should be "polynomial". (And congratulations on handling the archaic spelling; German has undergone two official spelling "reforms" since this paper was written.)

Comment: I like the phrase "we win the formula". We ought to start using it in English!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say "is able to attain" than "is possible to attain"?

Comment: Anyone knows what $\left|\underline{x}\right.$ means?

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It's a great translation!

Comment: @mvw: That is how they used to write $n!$ (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factorial.html)).

Comment: @TonyK Thank you very much for this information!